# android: how to align image in the horizontal center of an imageview?

Tags: android, alignment

I've tried all scaletypes, but all of them result in the image to be at the left corner of the imageview.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:background="#0000" 
    android:src="@drawable/icon1" />
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your ImageView has the attribute `wrap_content`. I would think that the Image is centered inside the imageview but the imageview itself is not centered in the parentview. If you have only the imageview on the screen try `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`. If you have more then one view in the layout you have to center the imageview.

Comment: I do have more than one view in the layout. What exactly do you mean by "center the imageview"?

Comment: The ImageView itself should be inside a layout component. This surrounding layout component can arrange the child elements... If you could post your whole layout file I could try to give you some more precise hints.

Comment: Yang - I think your problem is that the parent is a relative layout and not a linear layout.  If that's the case, then try android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" rather than layout_gravity.

Answer (score 86):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: If the parent is a `RelativeLayout`, use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

Comment: This solution works even if Android Studio doesn't show this attribute.

Answer (score 37):

You can center the ImageView itself by using:

`android:layout_centerVertical="true"` or `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`
For vertical or horizontal.  Or to center inside the parent:

`android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

But it sounds like you are trying to center the actual source image inside the imageview itself, which I am not sure on.

Comment: How to go about it when the parent is a LinearLayout?

Comment: Got it!! I guess if your parent is a LinearLayout, you could about setting an attribute in it's child ImageView - android:layout_gravity="center".
This worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

This works for me when aligning image view in linearlayout.

```
<ImageView android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:src="@drawable/find_icon"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="center"
    />
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this code :

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBusiness"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_detail" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please, provide some text explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Using "fill_parent" alone for the layout_width will do the trick:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:background="#0000" 
    android:src="@drawable/icon1" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

on the image in the `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 2):

For me `android:gravity="center"` did the trick in the parent layout element.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/fullImageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can horizontal your image view in a ***linear layout*** using:

```
 android:layout_gravity="center"
```

it will center your image to the parent element, if you just want to center horizontally you can use:

```
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Answer (score 1):

Give width of image as match_parent and height as required, say 300 dp.

```
<ImageView
    android:id = "@+id/imgXYZ"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "300dp"
    android:src="@drawable/imageXYZ"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this attribute:
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Answer (score 0):

This is code in xml of how to center an ImageView, I used "layout_centerHorizontal".

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img2"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

or this other example...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img2"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If this is intended to be an answer, please add some explanation. If it is intended to be a question, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

According [**`@charles`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587305/android-how-to-align-image-in-the-horizontal-center-of-an-imageview/13186147#13186147) answer you must add the following :

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

And this one :

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```